# Searching a record in SQL by an id in Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql

In my SQL database single record consists of four rows: id, name, age and email. How to get a single record by typing in a JTextField id of that record? So later we can for example `System.out.printIn();` it? I know that my question might be stupid for someone who is an SQL expert but I am only a beginner and after searching for this information in the tutorials I could not find it:(. Please help. Here is some of my source code:

```
    public static Connection getConnection() throws Exception{
            try{
                String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
                String url = "jdbc:mysql://some IP address/testdb";
                String username = "some username";
                String password = "some password";
                Class.forName(driver);

                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
                System.out.println("Connected");
                return conn;
            } catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}


            return null;
        }


    public EsquelTest() {

        IDname = new JTextField("");
        submit = new JButton("go");
        add(IDname);
        add(submit);
        submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(e.getSource() == submit) {
                    id = IDname.getText().toString();
                    try {
                        getConnection();
                        get(id);
                    } catch (Exception e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }

            }
                }


        });
        setLayout(new GridLayout());
    }

 public static ArrayList<String> get(String idname) throws Exception{
            try{
                Connection con = getConnection();
                PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("Statement needed to get the whole record by owning only an ID");

                ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();

                ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
                while(result.next()){

                    array.add(result.getString("last"));
                }
                System.out.println("All records have been selected!");
                return array;

            }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
            return null;

        }
```

Comment: That is very Basic of SQL. So you should know it as beginner

Comment: I think this is really basic. Maybe you don't get it from tutorial. Try learn logic and structure..

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking for only SQL statement it is: `select * from yourtable where id = theIdThatIsfromTextFieldHere`

Yet, if you simply google it you will find thousands of answers. [here for instance.](https://alvinalexander.com/java/java-mysql-select-query-example)

Comment: `from yourdatabase` --> `from yourtable`

Comment: Oh, sorry, Did not notice. Edited. @Jens

Answer (score 0):

The SQL Statement would be `SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE id = yourid`. So to embed it into your code it would look something like this:

```
 public static Connection getConnection() throws Exception{
            try{
                String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
                String url = "jdbc:mysql://some IP address/testdb";
                String username = "some username";
                String password = "some password";
                Class.forName(driver);

                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
                System.out.println("Connected");
                return conn;
            } catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}


            return null;
        }


    public EsquelTest() {

        IDname = new JTextField("");
        submit = new JButton("go");
        add(IDname);
        add(submit);
        submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(e.getSource() == submit) {
                    id = IDname.getText().toString();
                    try {
                        getConnection();
                        get(id);
                    } catch (Exception e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }

            }
                }


        });
        setLayout(new GridLayout());
    }

 public static ArrayList<String> get(String idname) throws Exception{
            try{
                Connection con = getConnection();
                PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM {REPLACE WITH YOUR TABLE} WHERE id = "+idname);

                ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();

                ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
                while(result.next()){

                    array.add(result.getString("last"));
                }
                System.out.println("All records have been selected!");
                return array;

            }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
            return null;

        }
```

Just a Tip: Don't name you function "get" as this is a commonly used keyword in other programming languages that only causes confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
public static Connection getConnection() throws Exception{
        try{
        String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://some IP address/testdb";
        String username = "some username";
        String password = "some password";
        Class.forName(driver);

        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
        System.out.println("Connected");
        return conn;
        } catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}


        return null;
        }


public EsquelTest() {

        IDname = new JTextField("");
        submit = new JButton("go");
        add(IDname);
        add(submit);
        submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() == submit) {
        id = IDname.getText().toString();
        try {
        getConnection();
        for(String string:get(id)){
            System.out.println(string);
        }
//        get(id);
        } catch (Exception e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        }
        }


        });
        setLayout(new GridLayout());
        }

public static ArrayList<String> get(String idname) throws Exception{
        try{
        Connection con = getConnection();
        // You should replace "YourTableName" With table in databace that you work with it
        PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM YourTableName WHERE id = '" + idName+"'");
        //If type of your id in database is Int write this code :
        //    int id= Integer.parseInt(idName); 
        //PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM YourTableName WHERE id = " + idName);

        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();

        ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
        result.next();
        //This array has all data in single recorde
        array.add(result.getString("id"));
        array.add(result.getString("name"));
        array.add(result.getString("age"));
        array.add(result.getString("email"));

        // I removed this rows becuse you have only one record
//        while(result.next()){
//
//        array.add(result.getString("last"));
//        }
        System.out.println("All records have been selected!");
        return array;

        }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
        return null;

        }
```